# gnome development resources

Tags: ruby, gnome, autohotkey, ruby-gnome2

For fun I'm attempting to write a light clone of autohotkey for gnome. All i really want it to be able to do is:

- move/maximize/minimize existing application windows
- launch gui applications(firefox, gedit, etc)
- change the system audio volume
- run from system tray

I have no idea really where to get started. Finding up to date information on gnome dev is pretty hard in and of itself and most of what I found is for building simple gui applications.  I haven't been able to find anything about how to get a list of active applications and manipulate their windows and whatnot. Can anyone point me in the direction at least of what tools would be good for this sort of thing? I'm on ubuntu and have been messing around in ajunta/glade and ruby-gnome2. A ruby library for this sort of thing would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't been able to find anything about how to get a list of active applications and manipulate their windows and whatnot

Did you look in [GnomeLove](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove)?

Comment: i hadn't, but it doesnt seem to be that exhaustive of a resource either.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking a reasonable solution would be to write in js to make a gnome3 shell extension - it's quite likely one the best approaches ...I am going to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't been able to find anything about how to get a list of active applications and manipulate their windows and whatnot.

You need to `sudo apt-get install` the packages `wmctrl` (for getting a list of active *windows*, not applications) and `xdotool` (for manipulating the window IDs you get from `wmctrl`).

To get the window ID for an application whose window title can be uniquely matched by the regular expression "FOO":

```
wmctrl -l | grep "FOO"
```

To get just the window ID for that window (use the `cut` command to retrieve only the first column):

```
wmctrl -l | grep "FOO" | cut -d' ' -f1
```

To do all the above and then assign the window ID you found to a variable:

```
BAR=$( wmctrl -l | grep "FOO" | cut -d' ' -f1 )
```

To (e.g.) minimize the window now identified by the ID now stored in the `BAR` variable:

```
xdotool windowminimize $BAR
```

Have fun!

PS: Here is a [gist of a shell script I wrote](https://gist.github.com/bokov/02d3b94cefcf81682ec5795220fa5f15) that bundles together the above steps.